# Problema de "falta api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll "

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

He instalado XAMPP en mi servidor, pero me da el problema de el programa no puede iniciarse porque falta api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll en el equipo, al intentar iniciar Apache.

Cabe aclarar lo siguiente:

1-El sistema operativo es Windows 7

2-Ya intenté instalar Visual C++ redistributable para visual studio 2015, pero eso no me funcionó
3-También intenté instalar la actualización para Universal C Runtime, pero tampoco funcionó

Comment: Instala C++ Redistributable 2013, 2015-2019 de 32bits y 64bits. Luego reinstala Xampp.

Comment: @aeportugal ya intenté con eso pero no me funcionó tampoco

Comment: quizás sea un problema con tener activado el antivirus?